# Penrose Theorem: Comparing 2 different physical quantities?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, units, singularities

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose%E2%80%93Hawking_singularity_theorems)-

> Penrose's theorem is more restricted and only holds when matter obeys a stronger energy condition, called the dominant energy condition, in which the "energy is larger than the pressure".

(inverted commas mine)

How can we compare 2 very different physical quantities of pressure and energy? 
I have thought some possibilities: 
1. The wikipedia page has a mistake.
2. It's simply energy is in large amount for the black-hole , bur pressure is low.
3.Some counterintuitive higher- level physics relation between those 2 quantities (It's very counterintuitive to me because my physics knowledge is very much limited to A level physics.)

But which of the 3 possibilties is true? Any wise words?

Comment: More restrictive than what? Is it the penrose theorum page - include a link?

Comment: Someone edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a realationship between the two quantities of energy and pressure, but, fortunately for you, it is neither counter-intuitive or higher level. When it says "energy" it really means "energy density". Now notice that the dimensions actually work out: from a relation such as $W=P\Delta V$, you deduce that 
$$[\textrm{Pressure}]=\frac{[\textrm{Energy}]}{[\textrm{Volume}]},$$

while clearly energy density has the same dimensions.

In fact, the dominant energy condition for perfect fluids is evaluated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_condition#Perfect_fluids) in the fourth bullet point, and you can see that the condition becomes

> $\rho \ge |p|,$

where $\rho$ is the energy density, and $p$ is the pressure.

Comment: Whoop! Someone should edit that wikipedia page.

Answer (score 2):

The actual condition is about energy density, which as you may check, has the same dimension as pressure.

$$\rho > |p|$$